# How to choose Online database for Android app

Tags: android, database, android-studio

Which is the best free online database for Android? It is for a management app and the data is structured with many different tables. And it's a SQL and retrieve data in the form of query .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Firebase Cloud Firestore, if its only database you need, it does a great job at simplifying all the configuration and operations to read/write.

Its a NoSQL database so not sure if it might be what you are looking for. It might be a bit harder to find specific pieces of data in the database but with the Firebase SDK everything is very accessible and easy to handle from your app. It's also free and easy for beginners to use.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is another NoSQL option.  You can get a free, 500MB server though [Mongo Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas).